# Big Space Before and After Enumerate

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate

I am typing an enumerated list, and when I compile there is about half a page of space between the list and the text surrounding it.  The code:

```
and $a,b\in\R$.  Then

\begin{enumerate}

    \item $\vecv+(\vecw+\vecu)=(\vecv+\vecw)+\vecu$

    \item $\vecv+\vecw=\vecw+\vecv$

    \item $\zvect+\vecv=\vecv$

    \item $\vecv+(-\vecv)=\zvect$

    \item $(a+c)\vecv=a\vecv+c\vecv$

    \item $a(\vecv+\vecw)=a\vecv+b\vecw$

    \item $(ab)\vecv=a(b\vecv)$

    \item $1\vecv=\vecv$    

\end{enumerate}

We have proven
```

It happens for every list I type.  I am working within a theorem environment, with newtheoremstyle

```
 \newtheoremstyle{mytheorem}
 {12pt}
 {12pt}
 {}
 {1.27cm}
 {\bf}
 {}
 {.5em}
 {}
```

Comment: you don't need blank line after *Then*

Comment: @Sigur That is spacing to help me read the code.  Eliminating it has no effect on the problem.

Comment: Perhaps a MWE example would be useful to help us to reproduce the same results on our end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blank lines introduce new paragraphs.

By placing a blank line before your `enumerate` environment, you're telling LaTeX that this is a new paragraph.  So extra space may or may not be added, depending on how you've set other things up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\noindent
and $a,b\in R$.  Then
%%
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=1ex]

    \item A is for Amy who fell down the stairs

    \item B is Basil assaulted by bears

    \item C is for Clara who wasted away

    \item D is for Desmond thrown out of a sleigh

    \item E is for Ernest who choked on a peach

    \item F is for Fanny sucked dry by a leech

    \item G is for George smothered under a rug

    \item H is for Hector done in by a thug

\end{enumerate}
%%
We have proven

\end{document}
```

[image]

By using the `enumitem` package, you can more easily control spacing within the `enumerate` and `itemize` environments.  I've illustrated above how to control the space that precedes the environment.

If you want to open up space to make your source document more legible, then I suggest putting `%` on each such line to prevent LaTeX from thinking that you're about to introduce a new paragraph.

Comment: Adding comments had no effect.  But, the enumitem package did the job.  Thanks.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 The effect may not be noticable in your document (we can't tell as you did not post a usable example) but it does have an effect, latex takes a completely different code path if you add a paragraph break before the enumeration. Normally you will get more vertical space, or indentation of following text, or both, although of course a documentclass can set the extra space to 0, so it may not show.